# MAGENTO - get 404 error when acces skin directory

Tags: php, flash, magento, module, skin

I developed a module in magento. I placed a package of flash and php files in skin directory (ex. `myhost/skin/frontend/base/default/lib/xxx/xxx.swf` and `myhost/skin/frontend/base/default/lib/xxx/xxx.php`).
I created it on my localhost (XAMPP), and not find an error. So, I create a magentoconnect module for it.

When I install it on server via magentoconnect, installation succes with no error. But, I get 404 error when I access php file on skin directory (`myhost/skin/frontend/base/default/lib/xxx/xxx.php`).

Any solution to fix it? or where should I placed my flash and php package files ??

Comment: Are you familiar with Magento modules? I don't believe any PHP file should be placed in /skin/-folder. It's merely for layout stuff. (css,js and the like)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One important note as a security concern is any `.php` file in the `skin/` folder will not get executed.

```
# Always send 404 on missing files in these folders
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(media|skin|js)/
```

This is the rule you will find in the `.htaccess` file of Magento.

Therefore, PHP files that are to be executed shouldn't reside within the `skin/` folder.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.. So, where should I placed my flash and php package ?

Comment: app/code/local/modulename    just go through some doc that says how to create module in magento. http://alanstorm.com/magento_controller_hello_world

Comment: @satish mantri i have also the same problem can you provide a way whare i can move .php file from skin folder so it's work properly???